# Perform vector calculation between each element of array with array

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have 2 one-dimensional numpy arrays `k` and `d`. I want to perform a simple calculation between each element of array `k` and whole array `d`.
How may I do it without a for loop? I would like to do a vector calculation.

```
>>> k = np.array([4.1, 3.2, 1.2, 99.2])
>>> d= np.array([   0.,    2.,    4.,    8.,   14.,  100.])
>>>
>>> for kk in k:
...     print 6 - (kk >= d).sum()
...
3
4
5
1
>>> 6 - (k >= d).sum()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,) (6,)
```

Have also tried the following and didn't work

```
>>> d = np.array([[   0.,    2.,    4.,    8.,   14.,  100.], [   0.,    2.,    4.,    8.,   14.,  100.], [   0.,    2.,    4.,    8.,   14.,  100.], [   0.,    2.,    4.,    8.,   14.,  100.]])
>>> k = np.array([4.1, 3.2, 1.2, 99.2])
>>> 6 - (k >= d).sum()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,) (4,6)
>>>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key here is to index one of the arrays with `[:, None]`. That will prefix their `shape` with `1`, causing each item of the array to be encased in its own array. That way, numpy will create a grid of calculations:

```
>>> 6 - (k[:, None] >= d).sum(axis=1)
array([3, 4, 5, 1])
```